# Maintaining back button when using wondow.history.pushState

Tags: reactjs, iframe, browser-history

I'm working with an application that lives in an iframe. I control both the iframe app and the parent app.

In one page in the iFrame app, the user can select filters from a dropdown. When that happens I am trying to update the query params in the parent url without refreshing the page. To do this, I use the following function:

```
const setIframeQueryParams = (activeFilters: SearchFilters) => {
    const filterSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(
      activeFilters as Record<string, string>,
    );
    window.parentIFrame.sendMessage(filterSearchParams.toString());
  };
```

Then on the parent side, when a message is received, it is handled by:

```
const onIframeURLChange = (data: iframePostMessage) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(data.message);
    const {origin} = window.location;
    let urlString = `${origin}${props.basePath}`;
    if (!!params.toString())
      urlString = urlString.concat(`?${params.toString()}`);

    window.history.pushState(null, "", urlString);
  };
```

This seems to work fine in setting the query params. But doing so messes up the history quite badly, so that pressing the back button doesn't take the user to the previous page. Is there a way to do this, so that the back button still takes the user to the previous page?